# Azure Powershell: Attaching NIC & Private Endpoint to SQL Server

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-virtual-network

**I currently working on a Microsoft Azure Powershell Script which would allow users to deploy/spin up a SQL Database.**

---

With the creation of this SQL database I need NIC to connect to a virtual network and private endpoint -> This private endpoint will then connect with SQL server -> then the SQL server connects with SQL DB. Yet I am struggling :/ The NIC is never attached to the endpoint, the private endpoint can never actually become created which leaves a whole in my code. As I write this I wonder if its the order as I have it backwards from what I list below (the goal). I create the DB then Server then NIC, Endpoint, and at the end try and set that to virtual network. This seems likely but I'll try it out - completing this post though just in case (Im usually wrong xd)

**GOAL:** Virtual Network (w/ subnets) -> Network Interface Card -> Private Endpoint -> SQL Server *(this will later connect with a VM but that's later)* SQL Server -> SQL DB

---

*I am still green to everything to be honest so if there's any    feedback or something I can word better, please let me know.*

---

I currently have a virtual network and a subnet setup and that functions well.

```
# Create a Virtual Network
$virtualNetwork1 = New-AzVirtualNetwork `
    -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupNameSPOKE `
    -Location $location `
    -Name $vnetName1 `
    -AddressPrefix $vnetAddressSpace1 

# Create and add subnet to virtual network
$subnetConfig1 = Add-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig `
    -Name $subnetName1 `
    -AddressPrefix $snetAddressSpace1 `
    -VirtualNetwork $virtualNetwork1
   
# Sync Vnet and subnet together
$virtualNetwork1 | Set-AzVirtualNetwork 
    
# Get Subnet ID
$subnetID1 =(Get-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name $subnetName1 -VirtualNetwork (Get-AzVirtualNetwork -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupNameSPOKE -Name $vnetName1)).Id
```

---

I have been stuck on this portion for a little bit now and just cant get by it, again I strongly consider the order may be off. The order may need to make more sense, I'll try this but if anyone knows and could confirm that'd be awesome. Any whoo... Creating the SQL Server and Database run no errors and are great. Creating the NIC doesnt have many issues

```
# Create a SQL Server
New-AzSqlServer -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupNameSPOKE -ServerName $serverName -Location $location -SqlAdministratorCredentials (New-Object PSCredential -ArgumentList ($adminLogin, $adminPassword)) -ServerVersion "12.0"

# Create SQL Database
New-AzSqlDatabase -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupNameSPOKE -ServerName $serverName -DatabaseName $databaseName -RequestedServiceObjectiveName "S0"

# Create NIC for SQL
$nicSQL = New-AzNetworkInterface `
    -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupNameSPOKE `
    -Location $location `
    -Name $databaseName `
    -SubnetId $subnetID1
```

---

The NIC works but sometimes the SubnetID parameter isnt wanted/needed, It works else where but it doesn't like it when I use it with my private endpoint. Towards the end here you can see the commented out solutions I have attempted which were unsuccessful

```
# Create Private Endpoint
#$privateLinkServiceConnection = New-AzPrivateLinkServiceConnection -Name $privateLinkServiceConnectionName -ServiceAlias "sql"
$privateLinkServiceConnection = New-AzPrivateLinkServiceConnection -Name $privateLinkServiceConnectionName -PrivateLinkServiceId "/subscriptions/$subscriptionId/resourceGroups/$resourceGroupNameSPOKE/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/$serverName"

$privateEndpoint = New-AzPrivateEndpoint -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupNameSPOKE -Name $privateEndpointName -Location $location -SubnetId $subnetID1 -PrivateLinkServiceConnection $privateLinkServiceConnection
$privateLinkServiceConnection | Add-AzPrivateLinkServiceConnection -Name $privateLinkServiceConnectionName -NetworkInterfaceId $nicSQL.Id -PrivateEndpoint $privateEndpoint

# Associate Subnet with Private Endpoint
#Set-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -VirtualNetwork $virtualNetwork1 -Name $subnetName1 -AddressPrefix $snetAddressSpace1 -PrivateEndpointNetworkPolicies $privateEndpoint.NetworkPolicies -PrivateEndpoint $privateEndpoint


# Attach NIC to Private Endpoint
#$privateLinkServiceConnection | Add-AzPrivateLinkServiceConnection -Name $privateLinkServiceConnectionName -NetworkInterfaceId $nicSQL.Id -PrivateEndpoint $privateEndpoint

#Set-AzNetworkInterface -NetworkInterface $nicSQL
```

Everything has consistently brought me errors and I feel as I am going in a circle. Any guidance would be amazing

---

Errors that give me headaches:

```
1) subnetID1 -PrivateLinkServiceConnection $privateLinkServiceConnection
     |                                            
     | Cannot bind argument to parameter 'PrivateLinkServiceConnection' because it is null.

2) $privateEndpoint.NetworkPolicies -PrivateEndpoint $privat …
     |                                                
     | Cannot bind parameter because parameter 'PrivateEndpointNetworkPoliciesFlag' is specified more than once. To provide multiple values to parameters that
     | can accept multiple values, use the array syntax. For example, "-parameter value1,value2,value3".
_____
Other Errors:

3) POKE -Name $privateEndpointName -Location $location -SubnetId $subnet …
     |                                                       
     | A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'SubnetId'.


4) ateLinkServiceConnection | Add-AzPrivateLinkServiceConnection -Name $ …
     |                               
     | The term 'Add-AzPrivateLinkServiceConnection' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
     | executable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct
     | and try again.
```

Again any guidance or advice for this please let me know it'd be a great help. Even if it's redoing this post to make more coherent sense. Sorry if there's any issues. PLease let me know what yall think, If i need to answer any questions, or should structure this post better. Thanks everyone in advance

Comment: It would make a *ton* more sense to use a declarative infrastructure as code tool like Bicep or Terraform for this. This would be trivial using the correct tooling.

Comment: Please clarify, is this a SQL Server inside a VM, or an actual PaaS SQL Server? Is the client on-prem or inside an Azure VM? If on prem, how do you want the client to connect this SQL Server? over the public internet, over a VPN, or over an already set up existing ExpressRoute? You need to do the "design" part of this first. Draw a diagram of where the client is, where the server is, and how they will connect

Comment: Anytime this powershell error pops up _The term 'xyz' is not recognized as..._ it means you have not installed the Powershell module. Install the required module and a lot of your errors will go away

Comment: Also extending the other comment, it might be easier to manully create what you want in the portal and export the ARM template and look at that. Then you can an ARM template (or it's big brother, BICEP) and deploy that definition with a couple of Powershell commands.

Comment: @Nick.Mc - ok I appreciate the advice, I haven't heard of a BICEP definitley more familiar with ARM but I'll look into this. Also Thank you - I'll double check to make sure all modules are installed. Lastly, this will be used remotely and we will be using Bastion instead of a public IP.

Comment: @DanielMann Thank you so much for this advice, looking into BICEP currently and understanding how this may be a better solution. Thank you!

Comment: Bastion doesn't let you connect directly to a SQL Server. It only lets you RDP to a VM. It sounds like you are talking about IaaS SQL here (SQL Server installedon a VM) in which case SQL Server is irrelevant here, you just have to get the VM NIC set up properly.

Comment: @Nick.Mc you have it exactly right use case and all. I have the portion where the VM has a NIC, NSG, Disk and connect to vnet. Im trying to do the same thing with the SQL db but the flow chart I was given has the NIC-> Private Endpoint->SQL Server -> SQL db. The private endpoint refuses to be created automatically not allowing the NIC to attach and then the SQL server has no connection to the private endpoint. I believe I will possibly need to connect this SQL server to a VM somehow - haven't got that far. LMK if you have any suggestions or definitely going with a BICEP - thank you again!!

Comment: You need to edit your question and be _clear_ about where / what the SQL Server is, where the client is. If you don't know that (it certainly seems that way since this is the third prompt to clarify) then that is the first thing to work out. From your last comment it seems the client is in the VM and the SQL Server is the PaaS version. You might want to actually just build this manually in the portal and get it working that way to see what kind of objects are created. FYI PaaS SQL (as created by `New-AzSqlServer`)  does not need a NIC, it uses a private endpoint instead.

Comment: Let me revise that... Azure SQL (PaaS) doesn't have a NIC, but if you create a private endpoint for it, it creates a NIC for you. You don't need to manually create a NIC https://demiliani.com/2021/01/22/securing-your-azure-sql-database-with-a-private-endpoint/

Comment: @Nick.Mc Ok I apologize for not wording correctly, still trying to get a full grasp of everything and how everything works in a actual work environment, Im still green to everything and just trying to learn. I am going to connect with my teammate so I can get a better understanding of the purpose/function of the SQL server. Also really appreciate your point of doing this in the portal for a clearer understanding and bringing up the NIC is autogenerated with the creation of the priv endpoint. Did not realize this till now and I think this had be held up for a bit too. Appreciate your time, TY!

Comment: @Imran thank you so much for your support and patience. I was able to implement this into the script, everything is functional and able to create the Private Endpoint, DNS, PLS, SQL db and SQL server. Big thanks to all your help and your knowledge. thank you!!

Comment: @STP Patience is a virtue my friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the same in my environment got same error like below:

[image]

This error occurs `New-AzPrivateLinkServiceConnection` cmdlet failed to create the connection and `PrivateEndpointNetworkPolicies` parameter is being specified multiple times. The parameter `-SubnetId` is not valid for the `New-AzPrivateEndpoint` cmdlet.

To resolve this issue ensure you are using valid **`subnetId`** using below command.

```
$resourceGroupName = "<RGName>"
$virtualNetworkName = "sqlvnet" 
$subnetName = "default"

# Get the subnet ID
$subnet = Get-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name $subnetName -VirtualNetwork (Get-AzVirtualNetwork -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $virtualNetworkName)
$subnetId = $subnet.Id

# Output the subnet ID
Write-Output "Subnet ID: $subnetId"
```

[image]

Created SQL server and database like below:

```c
# Set an administrator and password for the SQL server
$cred = Get-Credential

# Create SQL server
$parameters1 = @{
    ResourceGroupName = '<RGName>'
    ServerName = 'sqlsrver12' #SqlserverName
    SqlAdministratorCredentials = $cred
    Location = 'eastus'
}
New-AzSqlServer @parameters1

# Create database
$parameters2 = @{
    ResourceGroupName = '<RGName>'
    ServerName = 'sqlsrver12'   #SqlserverName
    DatabaseName = 'mysqldatabase'
    RequestedServiceObjectiveName = 'S0'
    SampleName = 'AdventureWorksLT'
}
New-AzSqlDatabase @parameters2
```

***Note*** that while creating private endpoint its automatically create new Nic with same virtual network and subnet like below:

You can make use of below modified Script:

```c
# Define your variables
$resourceGroupNameSPOKE = "<RGName>"  
$serverName = "sqlsrver12"
$location = "eastus"
$subscriptionId = "209654eb-1867-49dXXXX"
$vnetName = "sqlvnet"
$subnetName = "default"
$subnetID1 = "/subscriptions/209654eb-1867-49df-9395-7f0XXXXX/resourceGroups/Aks-rg-test/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/sqlvnet/subnets/default"   #use your subnetID here
$privateLinkServiceConnectionName = "MyPLSConnection"
$privateEndpointName = "MyPrivateEndpoint12"
$databaseName = "mysqldatabase" 
$privateLinkServiceConnectionGroupId = "sqlServer"  # Replace with the correct Group Id
$dnsZoneName = "privatelink.database.windows.net"  #use the same dnsZoneName

# Get your virtual network and subnet
$virtualNetwork = Get-AzVirtualNetwork -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupNameSPOKE -Name $vnetName
$subnet = Get-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -VirtualNetwork $virtualNetwork -Name $subnetName

# Create Private Link Service Connection with the correct Group Id
$plsConnection = New-AzPrivateLinkServiceConnection -Name $privateLinkServiceConnectionName -PrivateLinkServiceId "/subscriptions/$subscriptionId/resourceGroups/$resourceGroupNameSPOKE/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/$serverName" -GroupId $privateLinkServiceConnectionGroupId

# Create Private Endpoint
$privateEndpoint = New-AzPrivateEndpoint -Name $privateEndpointName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupNameSPOKE -Location $location -PrivateLinkServiceConnection $plsConnection -Subnet $subnet


$vnet = Get-AzVirtualNetwork -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupNameSPOKE -Name $vnetName
$Zone = New-AzPrivateDnsZone -Name "$dnsZoneName" -ResourceGroupName "$resourceGroupNameSPOKE"
$Link = New-AzPrivateDnsVirtualNetworkLink -ZoneName "$dnsZoneName" -ResourceGroupName "$resourceGroupNameSPOKE" -Name "Virtualnetworklink" -VirtualNetworkId $Vnet.Id -EnableRegistration
$config = New-AzPrivateDnsZoneConfig -Name "$dnsZoneName" -PrivateDnsZoneId $Zone.ResourceId
New-AzPrivateDnsZoneGroup -ResourceGroupName "$resourceGroupNameSPOKE" -PrivateEndpointName "$privateEndpointName" -name "$dnsZoneName" -PrivateDnsZoneConfig $config -Force


## Disable private endpoint network policy ##
$vnet.Subnets[0].PrivateEndpointNetworkPolicies = "Disabled"
$vnet | Set-AzVirtualNetwork
```

***Output***:

[image]

To check the **`GroupId`** use below command:

```c
$subscriptionId = "your-subscription-id"
$resourceGroupName = "<RGName>"
$serverName = "<your-sql-server>"

# Define the Private Link Resource ID
$privateLinkResourceId = "/subscriptions/$subscriptionId/resourceGroups/$resourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/$serverName"

# Get the list of supported Group IDs
$groupIds = (Get-AzPrivateLinkResource -PrivateLinkResourceId $privateLinkResourceId).GroupId

# Display the list of supported Group IDs
$groupIds
```

[image]

In portal private endpoint created with same virtual network and subnet like below:

[image]

Make sure to disable public access in sql server like below:

[image]

Created virtual machine and bastion now when I check the connectivity to private endpoint IP address returned the private IP address of the private endpoint successfully like below:

[image]

In bastion Install [SQL Server Management Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?preserve-view=true&view=sql-server-2017)    and connected like below:

[image]

[image]

***Reference***:

[Connect to an Azure SQL server using an Azure Private Endpoint - PowerShell | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/tutorial-private-endpoint-sql-powershell)

Comment: @Imran This works perfectly and is able to create the portion with no errors. Thank you so much for all your help :))

Comment: @SPT Patience is a virtue.

Comment: @Imran do you believe this would be better implemented using a PS script, or what are your thoughts on using a BICEP template - or are they similar in execution performance and versatility ?